# java.io OutputStreamWriter.writer blocks when not flushing frequently

Tags: sockets, tcp, socket.io, tcpclient, serversocket

I am writing data to socket.writer and what I see is If I don't flush frequently, writer gets blocked and never gets to flush ever. If I flush it for every write, it is just fine. I am not sure how to determine right frequencey of explicit flush

```
      while ((subQueue.readableElements()) > 0) {
        int batchSize = subQueue.getReadableElements(buf, 0, buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
            TcpStringClient.this.outwriter.write(buf[i].getValue().toString());
            TcpStringClient.this.outwriter.write(RECORD_DELIMITOR);

        }
      }

     this.outwriter.flush();
```

Any help highly appreciated

Comment: What kind of outputStream are you using?

Comment: It is `java.io.OutputStreamWriter outwriter`

Comment: It does not surprise me that an StreamWriter does not send the written values if it does not deem it enough data. Your data is being buffered instead, All flush does is send the buffered data. I don't know the implementations specifics...

Comment: I think something else is going on.  The writer would automatically try to flush if its internal buffer was full.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing to a socket, it will block if the reading end is slower than the writing end.

Flushing has nothing to do with it.

Comment: That's true and you helped me with the blocking issue on another question. In this case when I change the batchsize and flush for every 100 writes,  it is fine. If batch size is like 200 then, write gets blocked. The server side faster than this client size.